# Skipped row in a for each loop with a sorted column

Tags: vb.net, sorting, foreach, datagridview

**Context:**

I am updating a DataGridView (DGV) using a `For Each` loop. The column of this DGV can be sorted (*and must be permited*) and when I do some update it in the loop, the sorting is still active. Because of this, once the row used in the loop is dealt with, if the value in the sorted column has changed, it will move.

So lets say we are dealing with the first row, and it moves, then the second row becomes the first. On the next loop, it goes to the now second row (third at first) and skip the newest first one. (It's actually good that this happens... now i understand better how ForEach Loop works!)

**What i have tried:**

I have tried to disable the sorting before doing anything in the DGV using a ForEach on the columns and changing them to `NotSortable` and then putting it back to `Automatic` at the end, but it didn't change.

**My question:**

Is there a way to update rows of a DGV, with one of the column sorted, without the sorting taking effect while we modify anything?

Comment: Have you tried working with the underlying Data that is used to populate the DGV instead of the DGV directly?

Comment: @JayV I populate the DGV by adding rows to it and therefore don't have a Datatable or anything of the sort to work on.

Comment: Maybe a bit of a workaround, but what if you do all the editing in a DataTable and bind the DataTable to the DataGridview everytime the DataTable changes?

Comment: It's clearly the best solution the more I imagine it so yeah I'm pretty sure i will go with that. Since i'll probably work on it next week, do you know if the sorting will take effect after that? I can only imagine that the sorting will either rearange all row after we reassing a new DataTable to the DGV, won't sort anything, or the sort will just not be _active_

Comment: **Answer:** the sorting stays and takes effect when you join the _new_ Datasource! Thanks @JayV and  Alex!